# Unable to get the end of file using StreamReader

Tags: c++-cli, streamreader

I'm getting the next error using this code: (System.IndexOutOfRangeException)

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{

String^ str="C:\\somefile.txt";

StreamReader^ sr=gcnew StreamReader(str);

String^ mystr=sr->ReadToEnd();

int i=0;

while (mystr[i++]!='\0')  //what's wrong wth this check?
{
  Console::Write(mystr[i]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing says that the string in a `String` class has to be zero-terminated like an old C-style string. Instead you should be getting the length from the string object itself.

Comment: How to get a length of the string using StreamReader? I've googled it but didn't find any answer =)

Comment: @user2809652 If you check e.g. [this reference of the `String` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx), you will see that it has a [`Length` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx), that can be used to get the length of the string.